# how to construct an https POST request with drupal_http_request?

Tags: https, drupal-7, http-headers

I want to send a POST request to an https server.

```php
$data = 'name=value&name1=value1';

$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data,
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

$result = drupal_http_request('http://somewhere.com', $options);
```

I can't figure out out to implement the https options in the POST example code above.

Can anyone please explain me how to do this? I am quite new to PHP coding with Drupal, and I could definitely use the guidance.

I found that all is needed is to set it in the protocol. So I got to this code.

```php
$data = 'access_token=455754hhnaI&href=fb&template=You have people waiting to play with you, play now!';

$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data,
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

$result = drupal_http_request('https://graph.facebook.com/1000721/notifications?', $options);
```

It still doesn't work. If I post via Firefox with `https://graph.facebook.com/1000080521/notifications?access_token=45575FpHfhnaI&href=fb&template=You have people waiting to play with you, play now!` it works.

I am probably not constructing the request properly in Drupal.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get my code to work?

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference between using `drupal_http_request()` with a secure connection (https://), or without a secure connection (http://).

PHP must be compiled with support for OpenSSL; otherwise, `drupal_http_request()` doesn't support secure connections. Apart that, the only issue could be the proxy server not supporting a secure connection.

As side note, you are using `https://graph.facebook.com/1000721/notifications?` as URL for the request. The question mark should not be part of the URL.

I would also use [drupal_http_build_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7) to build the data to use for the request.

```php
$data = array(
  'access_token' => '455754hhnaI',
  'href' => 'fb',
  'template' => 'You have people waiting to play with you, play now!'
);

$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => drupal_http_build_query($data),
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

$result = drupal_http_request('https://graph.facebook.com/1000721/notifications', $options);
```